# Haxe: Are there defines indicating the current compilation target?

Tags: haxe, conditional-compilation

Does Haxe have any defines indicating the current compilation target, which can be used for conditional compilation?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, every Haxe target has it's own define.

```
#if js 
  trace("js");
#elseif php
  trace("php");
#elseif cpp
  trace("cpp");
#elseif java
  trace("java");
#elseif python
  trace("python");
#elseif neko
  trace("neko");
#elseif sys
  trace("sys");
#elseif flash
  trace("flash");
#elseif cs
  trace("cs");
#elseif macro
  trace("macro");
#end
```

> You can find more build-in compilation flags here:
>   http://haxe.org/manual/lf-condition-compilation-flags.html
>
> More info about conditional compilation:
>   http://haxe.org/manual/lf-condition-compilation.html

Comment: If you want the define values at runtime for some reason, you could use this macro snippet http://blog.stroep.nl/2015/05/compiler-define-values-using-macro-functions/